# Find all the possible real values for $a,b,c,d$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Let pairs $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ be roots of the equations $x^2 + ax - b = 0$ and $x^2 + cx + d = 0$ respectively. Find all possible real values for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: All of my work has been hand written. I am not sure how I could show it here. @RK01

Comment: When you try writing a question, on the right side, there is a Format column that has links to basic Math Jax. You could use the tutorial to help you write it out.

Comment: solve the system $$a^2+a^2-b=0,c^2+ac-b=0,b^2+bc+d=0,d^2+dc+d=0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have not learnt how to solve systems.

Answer (score 1):

By Vieta's formulas we have
$$
a + c = -a\\
ac = -b\\
b + d = -c\\
bd = d
$$
From last equation, $b = 1$ or $d = 0$.

I) $b=1$. So,
$$
a + c = -a\\
ac = -1\\
1 + d = -c
$$
From second eq. $c = -1/a$ and
$$
a - \frac1a = -a \Longrightarrow 2a^2 = 1\\
d = \frac1a - 1
$$
So, $a = 1/\sqrt2, b = 1, c =- \sqrt2, d = \sqrt2-1$ and $a = -1/\sqrt2, b = 1, c = \sqrt2, d = -\sqrt2-1$ are solutions.

II) $d=0$. So,
$$
a + c = -a\\
ac = -b\\
b = -c
$$
or
$$
a + c = -a\\
ac = c\\
b = -c
$$
From second eq. $c=0$ or $a=1$.

II.1) $c=0$; we have
$$
a = -a\\
b = 0
$$
and solution is $a=0, b = 0, c = 0, d =0$.

II.2) $a=1$; we have
$$
1 + c = -1,\\
b = -c,
$$
and $a=1, b=2, c=-2, d=0$ is solution.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the roots of the first equation is
$$a+c=-a$$
so $c=-2a$. And the product of the roots of the second equation is
$$bd=d$$
so $d=0$ or $b=1$.

If $d=0$ the second equation is $x^2+cx$ whose roots are $0$ and $-c$. That is, $b=0$ or $b=-c$. If $b=0$ the roots of the first equation are $0$ and $-a$, so $a=0$ and $c=0$. This gives
$$a=b=c=d=0$$
If $b=-c$ then $ac=c$, that is, $-2a^2=-2a$. For $a=0$ we get the same solution, and for $a=1$,
$$a=1,b=2,c=-2,d=0$$

If $b=1$ The equations are $x^2+ax-1=0$ and $x^2-2ax+d=0$. Then $b+d=2a$, or $d=2a-1$. Also, $ac=-1$ and therefore $2a^2=1$. This give us two more solutions:
$$a=\frac1{\sqrt 2},b=1,c=-\sqrt 2,d=\sqrt 2-1$$
$$a=-\frac1{\sqrt 2},b=1,c=\sqrt 2,d=-\sqrt 2-1$$